# python object creation in 3.6.0

Tags: python, class, object

i was just introduced to Classes in python.The program is made to calculate the new date when a date is given and the number of days to add to the date. I am running the given code, but i am getting the invalid syntax error, but the line number is not being specified. can someone explain what is wrong?
Thanks!
Code is in python 3.6.0

```
class Date(object):
months={1:31,2:28,3:31,4:30,5:31,6:30,7:31,8:31,9:30,10:31,11:30,12:31}
def __init__(self):
    self.date=0
    self.month=0
    self.year=0
    self.leap=False
    self.enter()
def enter(self):
    self.date=int(input("Enter the date: "))
    self.month=int(input("Enter the month: "))
    self.year=int(input("Enter the year: "))
    if self.year%4==0:
        if self.year%100==0:
            break
        self.leap=True
        months[2]=29
def __add__(self,day=int(input("Enter the number of days: "))):
    self.date+=day
    c=0
    for i in range(12):
        self.date-=Date.months[i+1]
        if self.date<1:
            self.date+=Date.months[i+1]
            break
        c+=1
    self.month+=c
    if self.month>12:
        self.year+=1
        self.month=self.month//12
    print(self.date,'/',self.month,'/',self.year
#main
ob1=Date()
```

Comment: The class definition needs to be indented.

Comment: There must be more to the error message than just "invalid syntax".

Answer (score 0):

You should fix the indent issue in yours code:

```
class Date(object):
    months={1:31,2:28,3:31,4:30,5:31,6:30,7:31,8:31,9:30,10:31,11:30,12:31}
    def __init__(self):
        self.date=0
        self.month=0
        self.year=0
        self.leap=False
        self.enter()
    def enter(self):
        self.date=int(input("Enter the date: "))
        self.month=int(input("Enter the month: "))
        self.year=int(input("Enter the year: "))
        if self.year%4==0:
            if self.year%100==0:
                pass
            self.leap=True
            months[2]=29
    def __add__(self,day=int(input("Enter the number of days: "))):
        self.date+=day
        c=0
        for i in range(12):
            self.date-=Date.months[i+1]
            if self.date<1:
                self.date+=Date.months[i+1]
                break
            c+=1
        self.month+=c
        if self.month>12:
            self.year+=1
            self.month=self.month//12
        print(self.date,'/',self.month,'/',self.year)
#main
ob1=Date()
```

Also, you can't use `break` outside a `for` loop. Change it to `pass` or something.

In addition, I suggest to you to look at the `PEP8` style guide [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to make yours code more readable.